# Excel messes up some dots (".") in a number

Tags: r, excel, excel-2010

I have a tab delimited file: 
[image]
I created this file in R as a data.frame and wrote it to the above file using `write.table(dataFrame,"filepath",row.names=FALSE)`. However after I opened this in excel I got some `#####` in my excel file: 
[image]
The only difference between the tab del file and the excel file is that in the excel file the `.` is omitted, but I don't have any idea how this is possible because most of the other numbers are just fine. Any suggestion to fix this problem is welcome.
**Update**
I can fit the data in the column: 
[image]
However there should be a `.` after the 1

Comment: Make the column a little bit wider.

Comment: This usually means that the number cannot be displayed in the space available. Just make the column wider in excel and your number should be there correctly.

Comment: Why would it do that for those two only? The dot is not in the formula bar.

Comment: The column width is causing the #### but the underlying number is incorrect as the decimal point is missing. Have you tried opening in a text editor?

Comment: Is it happening to every number with absolute value > 1?  I might check that the dot is actually a period and not some other similar looking character that R mangled in there somehow.

Comment: What happens if you double click the line separating column F and G (up on the column row, above row 1)? That should expand column F to fit the values. If it still shows `###` then there's a "deeper" issue.

Comment: the first picture is how it looks in the text editor @Jacob it looks just fine

Comment: @dww my mistake I meant "write.table"

Comment: how are you importing it to Excel? try data>from text

Comment: Thankyou  @Jacob I redid that I saw that the default for my excel uses both "." for Thousand and decimal seperation so I fixed my problem however it's quite strange that the other numbers are good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably your import settings are wrong regarding the seperation for thousands and decimals. Notice that the problem arises when the first number is `>1`. Excel interprets a number as a thousand if the first number is `> 1` , because it woudln't make sense for excel to convert a number which begins with a `0` to a thousand. So you have to fix this: 
[image]
You have to do this while importing the file in the last step, you have to click on `Advanced` and then set the Decimal seperator to: `.` and the Thousands seperator to: `,` (or visa versa, it's what you prefer offcourse but in your case it has to be this)

Comment: Isn't this exactly the same as what was already given in the comments?